# Loop input values in another sheet through cell reference then Copy formula value and paste it to another sheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[[image: enter image description here]]

[image: Updater sheet]

[image: Histoircal_vol]

I am working on two sheets
Sheets("UPDATER") = where input data is placed (more than 700 rows) and where data needs to be copied
Sheets("Historical_vol) = where i have kept the formulas (C9:N9) and input the records from updater sheet in cell A9 of historical_vol sheet.
The aim is to get the values of each of Underlyings pasted in sheets("updater").columns("AB") but the values get calculated from sheets("Historical_vol").column(C9:F9) then paste these values in sheet("updater")on each row starts from cell AD4.

```
Sub historical_vol()
Dim i As Long
Dim a As Worksheet
Dim b As Worksheet

lr = Worksheets("UPDATER").Cells(Rows.count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
Set a = Worksheets("UPDATER")
Set b = Worksheets("Historical_vol")
 For i = 4 To lr

 b.Range("A9").value = a.Range("AB4" & i).value
 'b.Range("C9":F9").Calculate
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
 b.Range("C9:F9").Copy
 NextRow = Cells(Rows.count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Cells(NextRow, "AD").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: or should i use do while loop ? kindly let me know if you are unable to see the snapshot of updater sheet and historical_vol sheet

Comment: @user2451335 can you please help

Comment: @NareshBhople Hi Naresh, thanks for addressing my request, i have attached the screenshots of both the sheets for your reference. Should you require any further info please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I notice the line `b.Range("A9").value = a.Range("AB4" & i).value` should be `b.Range("A9").value = a.Range("AB" & i).value`

As I see you are using `Application.Wait`, I assume it is for the calculation. So, I suggest using `xlCalculationManual` calculation and resetting it to auto once done as below.

```
Sub historical_vol()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'This will help to watch the status bar update

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim wb As Workbook, uPd As Worksheet, hV As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, cl As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set uPd = wb.Sheets("UPDATER")
Set hV = wb.Sheets("Historical_vol")

lr = uPd.Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
i = 0
For Each cl In uPd.Range("AB4:AB" & lr)
hV.Range("A9").Value = cl.Value
hV.Calculate
cl.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 4).Value = hV.Range("C9:F9").Value
i = i + 1

Application.StatusBar = i '& " / " & lr - 3
'View on status bar number of records completed out of total records (lr-3)
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Thakyou so much for your help @NareshBhople, i can see a lot of data is updating in the desired rows seems like its working but its been an hour and the code is still running. i had to stop it deliberately, can i add a progress bad, do you think its a feasible option in this scenario ? I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: reason being it takes approx 5 seconds to calculate the values (C9:F9) for a single entity, so for 700 entities it will take 700*5 = 3500 seconds or 3500/60 = 58 mins (approx 1 hour)

Comment: Seems a lot complex calculations? Are those UDFs or nested long functions? Making manual calculation and instead of copy paste assignment of values should work faster. I wonder how could you get results in 2 seconds wait time?

Comment: a complex one indeed. to calculate the value of C9 it takes the historical prices of last 1year from database then do log normal and stdeviation to calculate historical vol fo 30 days then do the same for column D9 (60days) and E9 (90days) then gives the average of 30,60,90 in another column which is why it takes time. i thought adding a loading bar will be fruitful as we will be aware how far have we reached in terms of completion.

Comment: Ohh!! That means its not just hV sheet that needs to be calculated? If so, instead of `hV.Calculate` just mention `Calculate`. In AF1 of Updater sheet enter `=COUNTA(AD4:AD10000)*100/COUNTA(AB4:AB10000)` to show percentage completed

Comment: thanks it worked like a charm, just two questions from the code that i couldnot understand
i = 0  (why we have taken it as 0)
cl.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 4).Value = hV.Range("C9:F9").Value (what is the use of offset and resize in this context)
hV.Range("A9").Value = cl.Value (is this a range cl.value)

Comment: but the cells on the updater sheet column AB are dynamic, sometimes they are less than 700 sometimes more than 700, number is not fixed

Comment: We are not using i to refer to a cell in Updater sheet. We are using it as a count of records completed, so that, it can be shown in the status bar. All the cell on the updater sheet column AB are referred to as cell which is range object.. Yes, Its a dynamic range. Please see `Each cl In uPd.Range("AB4:AB" & lr)`  that makes it dynamic.  So if lr is 1000 then range will be AB4:AB1000, If lr is 100 then range will be AB4:AB100.  If this answers your question please upvote/ accept it with a tick on the left of the answer

Comment: Refer [Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) and [resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) . Its faster to assign value of one range to another range using = than to copy and paste. So, value of `hV.Range("C9:F9")` is assigned to `cl.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 4)` using `cl.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 4).Value = hV.Range("C9:F9").Value`.

Comment: If this answers your question please upvote / accept it with a tick on the left of the answer.

Comment: Hi Naresh, i am trying to do something similar but getting error in this line of code cl.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 1).value = cv.Range("L3").value. can you please help ? i need the value F9 to be pasted next to input column...i have also attached a screenshot for your reference.

Comment: even trying the below didnt help 
cl.Offset(0, 6).Resize(1, 1).value = Range("L3").value

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are trying but not quite getting it. Your comment and the image seems contradictory.. Are you copying value of F9 to L3 or From L3 to F9

Comment: The first cl is K3  .. So `cl.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 1).value = Range("L3").value` means `L3 = L3` .. and .. `cl.Offset(0, 6).Resize(1, 1).value = cv.Range("L3")` means `Q3 = L3` and  `cl.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 1).value = cv.Range("F9")` means `L3 = F9`

Comment: so basically my input range is column K from column K all the Underlier (VOD.L, WMB.N) will go to cell A9 under heading RIC one by one and i need cell F9 value in column L3 till last row.

Comment: i believe this will solve the purpose
cl.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 1).value = Range("F9").value but why i was using offset(0,5) because from cell A9 it move by 5 columns and fall into cell F9 then resize (1,1) will select that cell and become cell value for = Range("L3").value